# Creating a valid XSD that is open using <all> and <any> elements

Tags: xsd, jaxb

I need to specify a XSD for validating XML documents. The XSD will be used for a JAXB generation of Java bindings.
**My problem is specifying optional elements which I do not know the names of and which I in general am not interested in parsing.**

The structure of the XML documents is like:

```
<TRADE>
  <TIME>12:12</TIME>
  <MJELLO>12345</MJELLO>
  <OPTIONAL>12:12</OPTIONAL>
  <DATE>25-10-2011</DATE>
  <HELLO>hello should be ignored</HELLO>
</TRADE>
```

The important thing is, that:

- I can not assume any order, and the next XML document instance migtht have tags in a different order
- I am only interested in parsing some of the tags, some are mandatory and some are optional
- The XML documents can be extended with new elements which I am not interested in parsing

The structure of my XSD is like (***not a valid xsd***):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!-- *********************************************** -->
  <!-- Trade element definitions for the XML Documents -->
  <!-- *********************************************** -->

  <xs:complexType name="Trade">
    <!-- Using the all construction ensures that the order does not matter -->
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="DATE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="TIME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="OPTIONAL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!-- TRADE is the mandatory top-level tag -->
  <xs:element name="TRADE" type="Trade"/>

</xs:schema>
```

So, in this example: DATE and TIME are mandatory (they must be in the XML exactly once), OPTIONAL might be present once and then I would like to specify, that all other tags are allowed. The order does not matter.

How do I specify a valid XSD for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic parser problem.

Basically, your BNF is:

```
Trade    = whatever whatever*
whatever = "DATE"  | "TIME" | anything
anything = a-z a-z*
```

But this is ambigous. The string "DATE" can both be accepted under the whatever rule as "DATE" and as anything.

So if you have

```
<TRADE>
  <TIME>12:12</TIME>
  <DATE>25-10-2011</DATE>
  <DATE>25-12-2011</DATE>
</TRADE>
```

it is unclear whether that should be accepted or not.

It could be interpreted either one of

```
"TIME", "DATE", anything
anything, anything, "DATE"
anything, anything, anything
"TIME", "DATE", anything
"TIME", "DATE", "DATE"
etc.
```

It all boils down to: If you have a wildcard combined with random sequence, you cannot meaningfully decide which token matches which rule.

It especially does not make sense to have optional elements together with a wilcard.

You have two options:

- use xs:sequence instead of xs:all
- do not use wildcard

As I understand it, both options are in conflict with your wishes.

Perhaps you can construct a wildcard that matches everything *except* DATE, TIME etc.

Comment: I had a suspecion that this was the case :-(
The extra thing I did not write is, that I know that elements will max appear once.

Comment: I ended up having a XSLT step before the parsing step. This works perfectly, first filtering all tags that I am not interested in away, and then validating according to a "slim" xsd only containing elements I am interested in.

Comment: What if I know that `whatever` will never be a `date` or `time`? Then there will not be any ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a hard requirement to have JAXB bindings to your "known" elements?
If not, you can basically have just `<any maxoccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>` as your xsd, and then pick out the elements you are interested in from the DOM tree.

(See [here](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Avoid_strong_databinding.html) how to use JAXB without data binding.)

Comment: I would like to have the databinding (or at least a reasonable tight XSD), as I unmarshall using XSD validation to check values, lengths and datatypes.