# Removing elements from an XML document, XSLT and JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsd, jaxb

This question is a follow up to my earlier question:
[Creating a valid XSD that is open using <all> and <any> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178255/creating-a-valid-xsd-that-is-open-using-all-and-any-elements)

Given that I have a Java String containing an XML document of the following form:

```
<TRADE>
  <TIME>12:12</TIME>
  <MJELLO>12345</MJELLO>
  <OPTIONAL>12:12</OPTIONAL>
  <DATE>25-10-2011</DATE>
  <HELLO>hello should be ignored</HELLO>
</TRADE>
```

How can I use XSLT or similar (in Java by using JAXB) to remove all elements not contained in a set of elements.
In the above example I am only interested in (TIME, OPTIONAL, DATE), so I would like to transform it into:

```
<TRADE>
  <TIME>12:12</TIME>
  <OPTIONAL>12:12</OPTIONAL>
  <DATE>25-10-2011</DATE>
</TRADE>
```

The order of the elements is not fixed.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy XSLT solution and an extensive explanation. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNames" select="'|TIME|OPTIONAL|DATE|'"/>
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*">
  <xsl:if test="contains($pNames, concat('|', name(), '|'))">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<TRADE>
    <TIME>12:12</TIME>
    <MJELLO>12345</MJELLO>
    <OPTIONAL>12:12</OPTIONAL>
    <DATE>25-10-2011</DATE>
    <HELLO>hello should be ignored</HELLO>
</TRADE>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<TRADE>
   <TIME>12:12</TIME>
   <OPTIONAL>12:12</OPTIONAL>
   <DATE>25-10-2011</DATE>
</TRADE>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The identity rule (template) copies every node** "as-is".
2. **The identity rule is overridden by a template matching any element that is not the top element** of the document. Inside the template a check is made if the name of the matched element is one of the names specified in the external parameter `$pNames` in a pipe-delimited string of wanted names.
3. **See the documentation of your XSLT processor on how to pass a parameter** to a transformation -- this is implementation-dependent and differs from processor to processor.

Comment: +1, then you can transform the XML using this XSLT to a JAXBResult to unmarshal the transformed XML:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181492/removing-elements-from-an-xml-document-xslt-and-jaxb/5181565#5181565

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried yet, but maybe the javax.xml.tranform package can help:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

**JAXB & XSLT**

JAXB integrates very cleanly with XSLT for an example see:

- [How to get jaxb to Ignore certain data during unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112404/how-to-get-jaxb-to-ignore-certain-data-during-unmarshalling/5118189#5118189)

**Your Other Question**

Based on your previous question (see link below), the transform is really unnecessary as JAXB will just ignore attributes and elements that are not mapped to fields/properties in your domain object.

- [Creating a valid XSD that is open using <all> and <any> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178255/creating-a-valid-xsd-that-is-open-using-all-and-any-elements)